# Monitor 3rd party bandwidth

Tags: monitoring, bandwidth

I know there are tons of tools out there for measuring network traffic, bandwidth, etc. But, are there any tools that can provide ANY information about an external sites bandwidth? *(A server/network we don't have access to)*

For instance, we have an agreement with an online media firm that is supposed to be providing services at "X" bandwidth level. However, due to slow downloads, streaming lag, failed uploads, etc. we think that maybe they are below the agreed bandwidth level.

Is there any tool, Desktop or Web app, that can give us some insight on this...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. Unless they have something doing that, give you access to it, and you trust them not to fudge the numbers. Refer to your purchase agreement and any SLAs you have with them.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You will need to inform them of the problems and ask them for their own metrics. If you have an agreement in place, they should be able to give you the stats you want. If not, time to find a new host.